# Injecting data to a page

Tags: php

Is it possible to do injections via PHP? For example, in the Firefox web console, I can go to my web page, and modify the input values of the form via the console by editing the page, and then send the page back to my server. I often do this to check for vulnerabilities. I am wondering if I can do a similar thing via PHP scripts? That is, sending form data inputs of a web page to that web page/server. The reason for this is that I want to automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can, and lot of people do that. With FireFox or Chrome or Fiddler2, you have interactivity but with `PHP` or `cURL` you can script and automate significant amount of vulnerability testing. Take a look at the usage of cURL http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#POST to POST data.

With PHP, one could use cURL also: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post and http://bavotasan.com/2011/post-url-using-curl-php/